# In PHP, how do you add whitespace around a non-square photo, so that it is always 200x200 pixels?

Tags: php, image, gd

This script below works fine to handle an uploaded image and resize it so that the max height or width (whichever side is longer) is 200px. So it could be 200x200 if it's perfect square image, or 200x140, or 140x200, etc.

```
if(isset($_FILES['image'])) {
        $img = $_FILES['image']['name'];
        $tmp = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];

        // get uploaded file's extension
        $ext = strtolower(pathinfo($img, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

        //checking if image exists for this pool and removing if so, before adding new image in its place
        if(file_exists("uploads/".$poolid.".png")) {
         unlink("uploads/".$poolid.".png");
        }

        // checks valid format
        if(in_array($ext, $valid_extensions))  { 
        //re-size the image and make it a PNG before sending to server
        $final_image = $poolid . ".png";
        $path = "uploads/".strtolower($final_image); 
        $size = getimagesize($tmp);
        $ratio = $size[0]/$size[1]; // width/height
        if( $ratio > 1) {
            $width = 200;
            $height = 200/$ratio;
        }
        else {
            $width = 200*$ratio;
            $height = 200;
        }
        $src = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($tmp));
        $dst = imagecreatetruecolor($width,$height);
        imagecopyresampled($dst,$src,0,0,0,0,$width,$height,$size[0],$size[1]);
        imagedestroy($src);
        imagepng($dst, $path); // adjust format as needed
        imagedestroy($dst);

        $_SESSION['image_uploaded']="yes";
        echo $path ."?".rand(1,32000); 
        } else {
          echo 'invalid file';
        }
    }
```

Now, Facebook sharing using OpenGraph requires an image to be at least 200x200. So a 140x200 image wouldn't work with their sharing functionality.

I don't love non-square images anyway, so I would like to take the image and if it's not already a square, I'd like to add whitespace to the sides (or on the top/bottom) and save it as a perfect 200x200 square every single time.

I tried this below, but it's not working (no image gets created at all).  What is wrong with what I tried to do?  This doesn't seem overly complicated but clearly I'm missing something.

```
if(isset($_FILES['image'])) {
    $img = $_FILES['image']['name'];
    $tmp = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];

    // get uploaded file's extension
    $ext = strtolower(pathinfo($img, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

    //checking if image exists for this pool and removing if so, before adding new image in its place
    if(file_exists("uploads/".$poolid.".png")) {
     unlink("uploads/".$poolid.".png");
    }

    // checks valid format
    if(in_array($ext, $valid_extensions))  { 
    //re-size the image and make it a PNG before sending to server
    $final_image = $poolid . ".png";
    $path = "uploads/".strtolower($final_image); 
    $size = getimagesize($tmp);
    $ratio = $size[0]/$size[1]; // width/height
    if( $ratio > 1) {
        $width = 200;
        $height = 200/$ratio;
    }
    else {
        $width = 200*$ratio;
        $height = 200;
    }
    $src = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($tmp));
    $dst = imagecreatetruecolor($width,$height);
    $orig_img=imagecopyresampled($dst,$src,0,0,0,0,$width,$height,$size[0],$size[1]);
    imagedestroy($src);

    // create new image and fill with background colour
    $new_img = imagecreatetruecolor($output_w, $output_h);
    $bgcolor = imagecolorallocate($new_img, 255, 0, 0); // red
    imagefill($new_img, 0, 0, $bgcolor); // fill background colour

    // copy and resize original image into center of new image
    $final_img=imagecopyresampled($new_img, $orig_img, 0, 0, 0, 0, 200, 200, $width, $height);
        imagepng($final_img, $path); // adjust format as needed

    imagedestroy($dst);
    $_SESSION['image_uploaded']="yes";
    echo $path ."?".rand(1,32000); 
    } else {
      echo 'invalid file';
    }
}
```

Comment: `imagecopyresampled` returns boolean, not another image resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a temporary intermediate image. You can paste the resampled source image right into the destination image after you fill it with background. See here:

```
  $src = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($tmp));  

  // Create new image and fill it with background color
  $dst = imagecreatetruecolor($output_w,$output_h);
  $bgcolor = imagecolorallocate($dst, 255, 0, 0);
  imagefill($dst, 0, 0, $bgcolor);

  // Copy resampled src image into dst
  if ($ratio > 1)
    imagecopyresampled($dst, $src, 0, ($output_h - $height) / 2, 0, 0, $width, $height, $size[0], $size[1]);
  else
    imagecopyresampled($dst, $src, ($output_w - $width) / 2, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $size[0], $size[1]);    

  imagepng($dst, $path); // adjust format as needed

  imagedestroy($src);
  imagedestroy($dst);
```